# não consigo alterar meu objeto vindo de uma dataTable - JSF com Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, java-ee, jsf-2.2

estou recuperando meu objeto do dataTable mais na hora que faço o redirecionamento do dataTable para outra pagina para fazer alteração, apresenta um erro. Mais pega o ID do Objeto, fiz um converter mais sem sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

meu Converter

```
    package converter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import dao.FabricanteDAO;
import modelo.Fabricante;

@FacesConverter(forClass = Fabricante.class)
public class FabricanteConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private FabricanteDAO dao;

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String value) {
        Fabricante fabricante = null;

        if (value != null) {
            fabricante = this.dao.buscarPeloCodigo(new Long(value));
        }

        return fabricante;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object valor) {

        if (valor != null) {
            Fabricante fabricante = (Fabricante) valor;
            return fabricante.getCodigo() == null ? null : fabricante.getCodigo().toString();
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Há um fórum próprio da Alura, que talvez te ajude mais rapidamente. Já tentou postar lá?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque a anotação `@FacesConverter(forClass = Fabricante.class)` por somente:

```
@Named
public class FabricanteConverter implements Converter {
```

Do pacote: `javax.inject.Named;`

Comment: Ajudou na resolução do seu problema?

Comment: Opa!  resolveu sim. obrigado